# Why Gradle is ignoring some of my dependencies?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have a project that uses some dependencies from a maven repository that is declared in the project's **build.gradle**:

```
  repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
```

The repository is the last line, sonatype.org.

My app's **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm:master-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:master-SNAPSHOT@aar'
    .
    . 5 or 6 more
    .
}
```

**I've checked they exist on the remote repository.**

My problem: Sometimes (and today specially) Gradle doesn't download **some** of those dependencies. It fails silently (no errors on the gradle console), but if I expand the project's "External Libraries" I see some of them missing.

I've cleaned the project, resynced gradle, etc ... but they are still missing. This already happened to me in the past and I remember syncing a couple times would fix the problem. But today I'm out of luck.

Obviously, the classes and symbols on the missing libraries are not found.

What can be happening?

Comment: Don't use dynamic versions for your dependencies

Comment: I know ... but unfortunately I'm forced to work out of the master snapshot because the included dependency is in an early stage and I also contribute to that project. Do you think that's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm ... lost 3 hours on this, while restarting Android Studio fixed the problem. Sigh.